# Bootstrap 5 - flex colums, children elements full width and equal height

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap, flexbox, bootstrap-5

[image]

I want elements on the left to be one below other, with equal height and width of the parent, and filling the whole height of the parent element (there will be 3 or more elements, 3 are here for testing purposes). Is this possible to do (I am using latest version of Bootstrap 5)?

HTML code:

```
<div class="row come-in">
    <div class="col-md-1 sections">
        <div>All</div>
        <div>Best</div>
        <div>Ever</div>
    </div>....
```

CSS code:

```
.sections {
  text-orientation: upright;
  writing-mode:vertical-lr;
  align-items: stretch;
  flex-flow: column;
}
.sections > div
{
   width: max-content;
   flex-grow: 1;
}
```

Comment: Please clarify what elements are you talking about. and add some pointers on the image.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Is this what you're looking for?

Pozdrav iz Slovenije. :)

```css
.sections {
  text-orientation: upright;
  writing-mode: vertical-lr;
  align-items: stretch;
  flex-flow: column;
}

.sections > div {
  width: max-content;
  flex-grow: 1;
}

.row {
  height: 500px;
  border: 1px solid red;
}

.col-md-1 {
  border: 1px solid blue;
}

.col-md-1 > div {
  display: inline;
}

.col-md-1 > div > div {
  border: 1px solid green;
}
```

```html
<link href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.2.2/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" integrity="sha384-Zenh87qX5JnK2Jl0vWa8Ck2rdkQ2Bzep5IDxbcnCeuOxjzrPF/et3URy9Bv1WTRi" crossorigin="anonymous">
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.2.2/dist/js/bootstrap.bundle.min.js" integrity="sha384-OERcA2EqjJCMA+/3y+gxIOqMEjwtxJY7qPCqsdltbNJuaOe923+mo//f6V8Qbsw3" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>

<div class="row come-in">
  <div class="col-md-1 sections">
    <div class="d-flex">
      <div class="flex-grow-1">All</div>
      <div class="flex-grow-1">Best</div>
      <div class="flex-grow-1">Ever</div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: To je to. Hvala puno :)